# How can I turn LIVE API calls into a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

What Im doing is, is running sentiment analysis on twitter and later plot it as a graph
The out put that i get is the sentiment and the date, like this:

```
6.49, 12/29/20 01:32:23 
2.69, 12/29/20 01:35:38 
2.08, 12/29/20 01:37:07 
-0.63, 12/29/20 01:38:35 
-1.46, 12/29/20 01:40:06 
-0.60, 12/29/20 01:41:36
```

Im running this code to save it to sentiment.csv:

```
f = open("sentiment2.csv", "a")
times = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%D %H:%M:%S')
f.write(str('{:.2f}'.format(polarity)) +', '+ str(times) + " \n")
f.close()
print("success")
```

and in my pandas file were i get ready to plot i run this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sentiment2.csv')


#print(df.to_string())

fig = px.line(df, x = 'sentiment', y = 'time', title='Ethereum sentiment')
fig.show()
```

And the error i get is related to the pandas head, because i dont have a head labeled 'sentiment' and 'time'. So how can i set up the head?
Ideally when i save to the csv file it should already be in the right format i can use with pandas. Or can i convert the csv file into a pandas object after reading in the csv file?

```
ValueError: Value of 'x' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['14.010626352813835', ' 12/29/20 01:11:02 '] but received: sentiment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can set up the head as follows: right format in csv

```
sentiment,time
6.49, 12/29/20 01:32:23
2.69, 12/29/20 01:35:38
2.08, 12/29/20 01:37:07
-0.63, 12/29/20 01:38:35
-1.46, 12/29/20 01:40:06
-0.60, 12/29/20 01:41:36
```

```
df = pd.read_csv('sentiment2.csv')
```

or  csv file into a pandas

```
6.49, 12/29/20 01:32:23
2.69, 12/29/20 01:35:38
2.08, 12/29/20 01:37:07
-0.63, 12/29/20 01:38:35
-1.46, 12/29/20 01:40:06
-0.60, 12/29/20 01:41:36
```

```
pd.read_csv('sentiment2.csv', names=['sentiment', 'time'])
```

both way all can, chooice by your perference

and figure it you can:

```
plt.scatter(x = df['time'], y = df['sentiment'])
```

by the way, usually we change time to integer by utc

Comment: how you cahnge time to an integer, just turn it into an int() or is there a special time format i can use?

Comment: this is the result https://i.postimg.cc/XvBVYwRy/Selection-999-235.png, the whole thing is a pet project, i just want to see the correlation between cryptoprics an the sentiment

Comment: usually we change time to integer by utc, because It can be modified easily .Sorry, I didn't make it clear. if do not want modify the date , forget it.

Comment: i do wanna change the date, please tell me if you dont mind

Comment: the only thing i found was turning the date into epochtimes format like this "1435371005653" is that what you mean by turning it into an integer?

Comment: your answer answered my question, however when i try to analyze the data with mean for example, i cant use sentiment as a header of my dataframe, so how can i turn this into a realy panda data frame with headers and a body

Comment: right..   "1435371005653" named  tiemstamp, which is  I mean.   above is the realy panda data frame with headers and a body(Series). you can't mean because the type is not right, default it is a object but float, you must convert it..... the code to  get mean of sentiment:             
df['sentiment'] = df['sentiment'].astype(np.float64);sentiment_mean = df['sentiment'].mean()